# How to get the data from WSDL file using touchxml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I‘m using TouchXML for parsing  WSDL file, and i'm a new to it, There's a NSString like this

`NSString *str = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soap:Body><ns1:createSessionResponse xmlns:ns1=\"http://soap.user/\"><ns1:out>9E0B34E6DFF7BF89</ns1:out></ns1:createSessionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";`

How can I get the string **9E0B34E6DFF7BF89** in "ns:out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSString *str = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soap:Body><ns1:createSessionResponse xmlns:ns1=\"http://soap.user/\"><ns1:out>9E0B34E6DFF7BF89</ns1:out></ns1:createSessionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
NSRange rr2 = [str rangeOfString:@"<ns1:out>"];
NSRange rr3 = [str rangeOfString:@"</ns1:out>"];
int lengt = rr3.location - rr2.location - rr2.length;
int location = rr2.location + rr2.length;
NSRange aa;
aa.location = location;
aa.length = lengt;
str = [str substringWithRange:aa];
NSLog(@"%@",str);  // 9E0B34E6DFF7BF89
```

Comment: ohh...do you want to use TouchXML?

Comment: thank you，Hector,  I find another way to get the session value directly. but your answer is still helpful to me.